# Getting Facebook ID from iOS settings

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

iOS has natively integrated already a way to login with Facebook. I see that apps like Medium uses these native Facebook settings. How can I access these settings? Is it possible to get the Facebook ID of the user logged in that way?

Comment: No way, to add the login via facebook account you should integrate facebok sdk for ios within your application

Comment: You can try [SLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/social/slrequest) of Social framework.